# Leaders killed or removed for reducing the privileges of the rich

Tags: taxes

The question is about leaders who reduced the privileges of the rich in order to help the poor. Until now, I've found two examples:

- Umar II (682 – 720), an Umayyad caliph, was greatly helping the poor by cutting their taxes and the rich people killed him because they could not digest his policies of justice, simplicity and equality.
- Johann Sachs von Harteneck (1664 – 1703), mayor of the German city Hermannstadt (today's Sibiu, Transylvania) was killed because he was asking the rich to pay taxes.

I am looking for more examples of such leaders who were killed or removed from power for reducing the privileges of the rich - or for reducing the taxes of the poor.

Comment: There is disagreement that Omar had been killed by poison, Many sources mentioned that he died of tuberculosis.

Comment: In case of Umar II, it was the royal dynasty who allegedly poisoned him. But then again, most rich people were members of the Royal house to begin with

Comment: Anyways, this is a list question and too broad. It would help if you were to specify a time period and a region.

Comment: Note that "reducing the privileges of the rich" does not mean that the ruler cared for the poor. For most of the history, there has been struggles between rulers and subjects, and unsurprisingly the most powerful subjects (i.e. the nobles) have been proven to be the most dangerous to the rulers ambitions and even lives.

Comment: Gustav III of Sweden perhaps as one of the reason was that he reduced the power of the nobles.

Comment: Cardinal Wolseley? He got in trouble for trying to shift the tax burdern towards the wealthy. But as noted, you're asking for a list.

Comment: That's what I meant with the question: reducing the privileges of the rich in order to help the poor. I noticed that, at least on other StackExchange sites, asking for lists (datasets) is ok - I assumed that it's ok to ask for lists here too. Like for example a list with leaders who were blind. Or who died of cancer. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list question *par excellence* but I'll allow myself to be tempted nevertheless...

- [Agis IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agis_IV) & [Cleomenes III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleomenes_III).
- [The Gracchi brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gracchi).
- [Kavadh I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kavadh_I).
- [Thomas Sankara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Sankara).

Comment: Didn't the Gracchi try land reform, rather than Robin-Hood tax policies?

Comment: @NeMo Same thing in practice: "Using the powers of Lex Hortensia, Tiberius established a commission to oversee the redistribution of land holdings from the rich to the unlanded urban poor. "

Comment: @NeMo There were other elements to their programme too (cf. the introduction of tax farming to Asia province, to get the equaestrians on their side) but the basic ideas was "Robin-Hood" all right.